# Store javascript variable in another .js file that contains an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, riot.js

Hello guys I am new to Javascript and I would like some help.

I am building a riotjs application that is showing posts from an array in a file postarchive.js

```
var posts = [{ image: "http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1140-400-4.jpg", title: "Post number 1", article: "Text of post number 1" },
 { image: "http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1140-400-10.jpg", title: "Post number 2", article: "Text of post number 2" },
 { image: "http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1140-400-5.jpg", title: "Post number 3", article: "Text of post number 3" },
 { image: "http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1140-400-3.jpg", title: "Post number 4", article: "Text of post number 4" }
 ];
```

What I am trying to do is that I want the Admin user to be able to extend the array in postarchive.js using a form I have created in Admin Interface.

In short, store posts without the use of Database but instead use the postarchive.js file.

Is this possible? If so can someone guide me to the right direction?

Comment: You need to write to file on server but would be better stored as json not as js variable

Comment: Ok so i ll create a function like this `var createPost = function(postImage, postTitle, postArticle) {
 posts.insert({
 image: postImage,
 title: postTitle,
 article: postArticle
 });
}` but how will i store it in the file??

Comment: You have to send data to server such as using ajax and write to file there